# I just upgraded to Xcode 9.3 gives Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, swift4.1, xcode9.3

My project was working absolutely fine, until the upgrade to 9.3. Right after the upgrade I started seeing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at my `AppDelegate` class.

[image]

I'm new to IOS development and this is my first Xcode update, are there any steps that I'm supposed to do to make sure my projects don't break like this on every update?

I'm using the Spotify API to mimic an instagram like feed and play songs from spotify on each post. Here is the bt

```
2018-04-04 22:32:08.479489-0400 Project2[43968:2765723] CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal:566:  Threw error #201 (XML parsingfailure)
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x0000000109f772cf libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getObjectType +47
frame #1: 0x0000000104b38e58 Project2`@objcAppDelegate.application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:) at AppDelegate.swift:0
frame #2: 0x0000000107adc33f UIKit`__58-[UIApplication_applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:]_block_invoke + 1037
frame #3: 0x0000000107adbc31 UIKit`-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:] + 652
frame #4: 0x0000000107ae8eff UIKit`-[UIApplication_handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 4851
frame #5: 0x0000000107e9466d UIKit`-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_CompatabilityactivateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1641
frame #6: 0x00000001088054d4 UIKit`__82-[_UIApplicationCanvas_transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] _block_invoke + 299
frame #7: 0x000000010880536e UIKit`-[_UIApplicationCanvas_transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
frame #8: 0x00000001084e962d UIKit`__125- [_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff: fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
frame #9: 0x00000001086e4387UIKit`_performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
frame #10: 0x00000001084e94f7 UIKit`- [_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
frame #11: 0x0000000108265fb0 UIKit`-[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
frame #12: 0x00000001080a2f89 UIKit`-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgentscene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 502
frame #13: 0x000000011094ed2d FrontBoardServices`__80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 + 198
frame #14: 0x000000010ac2c848 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
frame #15: 0x000000010ac31e14 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
frame #16: 0x0000000110982470 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
frame #17: 0x000000011098212e FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
frame #18: 0x000000011098268e FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
frame #19: 0x0000000106944bb1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
frame #20: 0x00000001069294af CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 +271
frame #21: 0x0000000106928a6f CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1263
frame #22: 0x000000010692830b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
frame #23: 0x000000010da7aa73 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
frame #24: 0x0000000107ad30b7 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
* frame #25: 0x0000000104b393f7 Project2`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
frame #26: 0x000000010aca9955 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Can someone help please? Has anyone seen anything of this sort?

Comment: you need to dig out more , debug and see at what point got crash ? right now your logs not showing any clue

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069361/exc-bad-access-in-facebook-sdk-login-xcode-8-beta/39260549#39260549. Stop using the deprecated delegate method.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 ! That worked!

Comment: No problem.  This bit me too after the 9.3 upgrade.

Comment: Holy hell that's an aggressive deprecation stance. What a surprise! </!>