# Using SFAuthenticationSession to log in user to Microsoft Graph

Tags: ios, swift, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using [p2-oauth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2) library earlier to be able to log in through a `safariViewController`, but since the latest iOS version (11.3) I found out that my app were crashing all the time when the user tries to log in. I didn't get any error messages, but after a while I found out that `SFAuthenticationSessions` is the way to go when using SSO (single sign on).

My old code were pretty much like this (Using p2_oauth2):

```
static var oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: [
    "client_id": "myClientID",
    "authorize_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "token_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "scope": "User.Read Mail.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Offline_access",
    "redirect_uris": ["myRedirectURI"],
    "keychain": true
    ])

func loginToOffice365(completion: @escaping (_ error: Error? ) -> ()) {
    var userDataRequest: URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/")!)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(OauthManager.oauth2.accessToken ?? "")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        return request
    }

    alamofireManager.request(userDataRequest).validate().responseJSON { 
 (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success( _):
    //Handle user information
        completion(nil)
    case .failure(let error):
        completion(error)
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to implement in `SFAuthenticationSession` in my project, and it was requiring a URL as a parameter. So I have been searching for a while for a Microsoft URL to make it possible to send in clientId, scope, and redirectURI in the same URL. And here's the result so far:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=78E99F6B&response_type=code&scope=User.Read+Mail.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite+Calendars.Read+Calendars.Read.Shared&redirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI&client_id=MYCLIENTID")!
        OauthManager.authenticationSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: nil, completionHandler: { (successUrl: URL?, error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(error)
            } else {
                var accessToken = ""
                if let absolutString = successUrl?.absoluteString, let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: absolutString)?.query {
                    accessToken = urlComponents
                }
                print(accessToken)
                completion(nil)
            }
        })
        OauthManager.authenticationSession?.start()
```

So now I finally received an access token from Microsoft. But where should I go from here? How do I get refresh tokens, make it possible to start calling Microsoft graph API calls?

If you know any better solution or any advice I'll be glad to receive them! This is my first project using login, because I'm fairly new to Swift.

**Update:**

I can also mention that Microsoft documentation recommends using these libraries:

- Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) client libraries are
  available for .NET, JavaScript, Android, and Objective-C. All
  platforms are in production-supported preview, and, in the event
  breaking changes are introduced, Microsoft guarantees a path to
  upgrade.
- Server middleware from Microsoft is available for .NET Core and
  ASP.NET (OWIN OpenID Connect and OAuth) and for Node.js (Microsoft
  Azure AD Passport.js).
- The v2.0 endpoint is compatible with many third-party authentication
  libraries.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview

I've tried MSAL and AppAuth, but they just didn't gave me any response back.

Comment: What method do you have in your app delegate to handle the call back? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069361/exc-bad-access-in-facebook-sdk-login-xcode-8-beta/39260549#39260549

Comment: You sir, saved me! I was using kind a like function in appDelegate, but I tried yours and voila! it's just working perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. It bit me too. It is tricky to debug because the exception and stack trace aren't particularly helpful.

Comment: You need to request the scope `offline_access` in order obtain a `refresh_token`. You may want to take a look at http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/

Comment: I went back to the p2-oauth2 library and tried Paulw11 answer and it suddenly start working perfectly again. In the code above I was using p2_oauth2 and used offline_access in the scope to get the refresh token. But thanks anyway! @Marc LaFleur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Paulw11 found the answer.

I was using a method, which worked fine up until XCode 9.3 and iOS 11.3:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But I had to change to the following method to make it work:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Xcode 9.4 and worked fine as we tested it. There is indeed a problem on Xcode 9.3