# iOS Facebook login crash

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I am using FBSDK 4.32.0, which keeps crashing for iOS 11.3 version, please help me, I have tried different devices which has different iOS versions, unfortunately, all the versions are crashing, below is my code

```
    @IBAction func didTapLogainAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
                    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
                        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                            if (error == nil){
                                let dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                                let alrt = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Logged in", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                let alrtDon = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                                    print("Perfect")
                                })
                                alrt.addAction(alrtDon)
                                self.present(alrt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                                self.LoginViaFacebook(dict: dict as NSDictionary)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your crash report

Comment: Ian it related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773318/using-sfauthenticationsession-to-log-in-user-to-microsoft-graph?noredirect=1#comment86566690_49773318 ?

Answer (score 2):

In 'AppDelegate' file, replace function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    // your code here
    return true
}
```

by

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // your code here
    return true
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In appdelegate copy paste this code first

```
AppDelegate.swift File

 import FBSDKCoreKit
 import FBSDKLoginKit


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
            return true
        }



func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation])
        return handled
    }
```

Now paste this on Viewcontroller and link to button action

```
@IBAction func loginWithFB(_ sender: Any) {

//        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
//
//        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions:["public_profile","user_friends","email"], from: self) {
//            loginResult,error in
//
//            print("completion handler called")
//        }
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: [ "public_profile" ,"email" ], from: self) { loginResult,error  in

            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            }else if(loginResult?.isCancelled)!{
                print("result cancelled")
            }else {
                print("success")

                FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil){
                        let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
                        print(fbDetails)
                    }else{
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Not found")
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know still if you are getting problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it's working for me. for more info [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)

```
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit

//MARK: Login With Facebook
   func loginWithFacebook(controllerName:UIViewController, completion:@escaping (_ IsSuccess:Bool,_ Response:Any,_ CheckInternet:String) -> Void)
    {
        /*Here you have 3 things compulsory
        1.FacebookAppId
        2.FacebookDisplay name
        3. add URL schema to add in infor plist file.
         <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleTypeRole</key><string>Editor</string><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array>

         <string>-----------------------fb123123123---------------------</string>

         </array></dict></array>
        */


        FBSDKSettings.setAppID(FacebookAppID)
        FBSDKSettings.setDisplayName(FacebookDisplayName)

        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile,.email], viewController: controllerName) { (loginResult) in
            if loginResult.self != nil{

                let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,name,first_name, last_name, picture, age_range, gender,  locale,link,timezone,updated_time,verified,address,birthday"], accessToken: AccessToken.current, httpMethod: .GET, apiVersion: FacebookCore.GraphAPIVersion.defaultVersion)
                request.start { (response, result) in
                    print(result)
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        if value.dictionaryValue != nil{
                            completion(true,value.dictionaryValue!,"")
                        }else
                        {
                            completion(false,"","")
                        }
                    case .failed(let error):
                        completion(false,"\(error)","")
                    }
                }
            }else
            {
                completion(false,"","")
            }
        }
    }
```